# NSRangeException on FetchedResultsController

Tags: objective-c, core-data

this could be a simple problem to solve but it has me stumped.

Background:
I have a very simple UITableView that is linked to a FetchedResultsController. Basically the table populates one row for every row in the FetchedResultsController.

Problem statement:
If I click on a button on my app to view all the records, the app crashes with the error

> NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[_PFBatchFaultingArray objectAtIndex:]: index (2) beyond bounds (2)

However, if I click on another button that presents a screen to add data, cancel out of this screen without saving anything and go back to the view all screen the screen works perfectly fine.

I even tried debugging with NSLog statements which you can see below

```
2012-06-01 23:37:01.345 TC[35258:fb03] sections : 1
2012-06-01 23:37:43.154 TC[35258:fb03] rows 3
2012-06-01 23:39:29.174 TC[35258:fb03] indexpath <NSIndexPath 0x91180f0> 2 indexes [0, 0]
2012-06-01 23:41:29.041 TC[35258:fb03] indexpath <NSIndexPath 0x903e770> 2 indexes [0, 1]
2012-06-01 23:41:44.015 TC[35258:fb03] indexpath <NSIndexPath 0x904afb0> 2 indexes [0, 2]
2012-06-01 23:41:46.598 TC[35258:fb03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[_PFBatchFaultingArray objectAtIndex:]: index (2) beyond bounds (2)'
```

This has me confused - when there are clearly 3 rows, why does it throw an error on the third row? Your help and insight is much appreciated. Thank You

Comment: Its like.. the number of records in the `fetchedResultsController` & number of records u collected in array that ur populating in `UITableView` are not matching. Array is going out of bounds

Comment: I understand that but i cant understand why they arent matching when the NSLog shows there are 3 rows in FRC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem and solution. Here is what was happening

1. In the main menu of my application, I have two buttons - one to add new items to the database and another to view all the items in my database
2. The above error was occurring if I viewed all the items directly from the main menu without trying to add something first.
3. I realized that if I go to the add screen and cancel out of the add screen, I was still creating an object in the ManagedObjectContext but wasn't deleting it when I cancel out. Hence the system still counted 3 rows of MamagedObjects but actually found only 2 committed ones in the database.
4. I added a line the cancel button code to delete the current managed object from the context, deleted the app from the iOS simulator, recompiled and ran it - works like a charm.

You may have the same issue - try the following steps to identify if your issue is similar

1. Delete the app from the simulator, compile it fresh and run it. If it works fine then there is definitely a conflict between the context and the database
2. Check to ensure that you are deleting managed objects you may have created but not committed.